# Magento 2 custom module images folder not deploying to pu/static on developer mode

Tags: module, magento-2.1.7, static-content-deploy

I am constantly failing to try to deploy `images` folder from my custom module to

```
pub/static
```

I have `css`, `js` and `images` folder in my custom module but only `js` and `CSS` are deployed to pub/static.

Comment: Here is an update maybe it will help you help me.
now when I run

 **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB** with language specified 

It will deploy **images** folder from my custom module but it does not creating symbiolic links can anyone help please? thank's

Comment: @userpk. Thank's for the edit suggestion but I appreciate if you focus on what's important here in try help me out would be great can you do that? thanks.